# How to customize parameters the way parameters list is built in Spring JPA?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data

I'm trying to invoke DB function with a method in Spring JPA repository like this:

```
@Query(value = "select * test.getVals(:ids)", nativeQuery = true)
```

When I invoke it manually, I do:

```
select * from test.getVals(array[2, 14577])
```

However, SQL that is being generated looks differently:

```
select * from test.getVals(?, ?, ?)
```

This syntax doesn't work.
Is there a good way to customize how these parameters are converted into SQL? so that I could have array[?, ?]?

If I do:

```
array[:ids]
```

It's converted with () like this:

```
array[(?, ?)]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
array[:ids]
```

If we take the list it converts into comma-separated values enclosed by parenthesis.

```
array[(?, ?)]
```

Alternative to this we can use the string value

```
List<Integer> ids = new List<Integer>{1,2,3};
String idsString = string.Join(",", ids);
```

This is we get

```
arry[:idsString] => array[?,?]
```